# Variables in Firebase Cloud Function returning "Undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am playing around with firebase cloud functions and I can't quite get it to run without an error.
It keeps saying that userID is undefined.

[image]

Here is the structure for the database:

[image]

And here is the code I am running for the function:

```
exports.observeMentions = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{uid}/{notificationId}/mentioned').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  var uid = context.params.uid;
  var notificationId = context.params.notificationId;

  return admin.database().ref('/notifications/' + uid + '/' + notificationId + '/uid').once('value', snapshot => {
    var userUID = snapshot.val();

    return admin.database().ref('/users/' + userID).once('value', snapshot => {
      var userThatMentioned = snapshot.val();

      return admin.database().ref('/notifications/' + uid + '/' + notificationId + '/uid').once('value', snapshot => {
        var type = snapshot.val();

         return admin.database().ref('/users/' + uid).once('value', snapshot => {
          var user = snapshot.val();


    if ((type = 3)){
        var payload = {
          notification: {
            body: userThatMentioned.username + ' Mentioned you in a comment'
          }
        };
    }else{
        var payload = {
          notification: {
            body: userThatMentioned.username + ' Mentioned you in their post'
          }
        };
    }


    if (userUID != uid){
        admin.messaging().sendToDevice(user.fcmToken, payload)
          .then(function(response) {
            // Response is a message ID string.
            console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
          console.log('Error sending message:', error);
            }); 
          }
       })
     })
   })
  })
})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Edit/Attempt:

```
exports.observeMentioned = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{uid}/{notificationId}/mentioned').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    var uid = context.params.uid;
    var notificationId = context.params.notificationId;

    return admin.database().ref('/notifications/' + uid + '/' + notificationId + '/uid').once('value')
        .then(snapshot => {

            var userID = snapshot.val();
            return admin.database().ref('/users/' + userID).once('value');
        })
        .then(snapshot => {

            var userThatMentioned = snapshot.val();
            return admin.database().ref('/notifications/' + uid + '/' + notificationId + '/type').once('value');
        })
    .then(snapshot => {

            var type = snapshot.val();
            return admin.database().ref('/users/' + uid).once('value');
        })
        .then(snapshot => {

            var user = snapshot.val();
    if ((type == 3)){
        var payload = {
          notification: {
            body: userThatMentioned.username + ' Mentioned you in a comment'
          }
        };
    }else{
        var payload = {
          notification: {
            body: userThatMentioned.username + ' Mentioned you in their post'
          }
        };
    }

            return payload
        })  
        .then(snapshot => {
            var payload = snapshot.val();
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(user.fcmToken, payload);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Error sending message:', error);
        });
});
```

This keeps getting the error:

Error sending message: ReferenceError: Type is not defined.

I don't understand why type is not defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a scoping problem.
Your variables `user`, `userThatMentioned`, and `type` are defined in the chained promises but are out of scope by the time you need to use them in later Promises.

I'd recommend declaring `user`, `userThatMentioned`, and `type` up where you're defining `uid` and `notificationId`. That way these variables can be accessed anywhere inside your chained Promises. You don't even have to define them at that point, just hoist them up!

Likewise, the declaration of `var payload` is only valid inside the scope of the if/else statement. I've corrected these scope problems so you can see the difference.

**IMPORTANT**

In the long-run you should definitely consider installing a linter in the code editor you use. It will catch these problems for you. My go-to, [ESLint](https://eslint.org/), underlines the problem and hovering over it will tell you exactly what's going on.

You also *absolutely need* familiarize yourself with the concept of [scope](https://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html#h_XqQR5FlX+8) because it's a very important part of writing successful code in *any* language.

Bonne chance!

```js
const { firestore } = require("firebase")
const { functions } = require("firebase")

const admin = firestore.admin()
exports.observeMentioned = functions.database
  .ref("/notifications/{uid}/{notificationId}/mentioned")
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    var uid = context.params.uid
    var notificationId = context.params.notificationId
    var user                // HOISTED
    var type                // HOISTED
    var userThatMentioned   // HOISTED

    return admin
      .database()
      .ref("/notifications/" + uid + "/" + notificationId + "/uid")
      .once("value")
      .then((snapshot) => {
        var userID = snapshot.val()
        return admin
          .database()
          .ref("/users/" + userID)
          .once("value")
      })
      .then((snapshot) => {
        userThatMentioned = snapshot.val()
        return admin
          .database()
          .ref("/notifications/" + uid + "/" + notificationId + "/type")
          .once("value")
      })
      .then((snapshot) => {
        type = snapshot.val()
        return admin
          .database()
          .ref("/users/" + uid)
          .once("value")
      })
      .then((snapshot) => {
        user = snapshot.val()
        var payload // HOISTED
        if (type == 3) {
          payload = {
            notification: {
              body: userThatMentioned.username + " Mentioned you in a comment",
            },
          }
        } else {
          payload = {
            notification: {
              body: userThatMentioned.username + " Mentioned you in their post",
            },
          }
        }

        return payload // RETURNING AN OBJECT...
      })
      .then((payload) => { // ... TO THE NEXT PROMISE
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(user.fcmToken, payload)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error)
      })
  })
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, but this still comes up with error:
"Error sending message: TypeError: snapshot.val is not a function"
Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks

Comment: It looks like the last `.then()` is incorrect because `payload` (the value returned from the prior Promise) is just an object, not a DataSnapshot. I'll update the code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There are several parts of your code that need to be corrected:

1. You define a variable as `var userUID = snapshot.val();` and in the next line you use `userID` (`return admin.database().ref('/users/' + userID)`) => Hence the "Undefined" error.
2. In a `if` check you should use the [equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) (`==` or `===`)
3. Instead of using the callback version of the [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference?authuser=0#once) method, use the Promise version and [chain the promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining) returned by the `once()` method calls with `then()`, as shown below.
4. Don't forget to return the promise returned by the `sendToDevice()` method. See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) for more details on how important this last point is.

---

```
exports.observeMentions = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{uid}/{notificationId}/mentioned').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    var uid = context.params.uid;
    var notificationId = context.params.notificationId;

    return admin.database().ref('/notifications/' + uid + '/' + notificationId + '/uid').once('value')
        .then(snapshot => {

            var userID = snapshot.val();
            return admin.database().ref('/users/' + userID).once('value');
        })
        .then(snapshot => {

            var userThatMentioned = snapshot.val();
            return admin.database().ref('/notifications/' + uid + '/' + notificationId + '/uid').once('value');
        })
        .then(snapshot => {
            // ....
            // return a Promise
        })
        .then(snapshot => {
            // ....
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(....);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // ...
        });
});
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, I have try to implement your answer however I am still having trouble. My attempt is shown above under Edit,
I am unsure why this error is occuring